# htaccess does not find my url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following path

```
root
--cp
----course-details.php
```

and I need the following url

```
/category/course-name
```

the course-details.php use the course-name in the url in order to find the course and show the information on the course details.

I tried in differents ways, but I can't make it. This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/artes-escenicas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/ciencia-y-tecnologia/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/arte-y-diseno/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/deportes/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/idiomas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/academico/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/rutas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/voluntariado/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

please any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use this code in root .htaccess (a level above `/cp/`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^artes-escenicas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^ciencia-y-tecnologia/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^arte-y-diseno/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^deportes/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^idiomas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^academico/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^rutas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^voluntariado/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cp%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ cp/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, I just tried your code, but I still getting The requested URL /artes-escenicas/campamento-artstico-vermont.php was not found on this server.

Comment: on my server I have a folder "web" and inside this folder I have .htacces and the cp folder

Comment: correct the course-details.php is in the /cp/ folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72064/discussion-between-jean-and-anubhava).